# Xcode 10 on macbook- How to comment /* */ shortcut

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, xcode

I'm using Xcode 10 on macbook for writing C program.
How can I make a block of comment with keyboard shotcut like this example:

```
 /*
 * class.c
 *
 *  Created on: Jul 30, 2019
 *      Author: abbn
 */
```

I know how to comment with: cmd + /
but it creates comments with // and not /*